# Oracle 11.2 ORA-00604

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting this error and don't know how to resolve it.

An error was encountered performing on SQL Developer when processing any  operation (query, structure view, etc.):

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-01578: ORACLE data block corrupted (file # 1, block # 94646)
ORA-01110: data file 1: '+DATA/***/system01.dbf'
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
Vendor code 604
```

Background:

- Oracle Version: 11.2
- Platform: VirtualBox
- Installation: VirtualBox Appliance

Question:

- How to resolve this?
- Where is `+/DATA/***/system01.dbf` located in the linux workspace?

Comment: Could you share your query with us?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it isn't just one query. Even I do share it, it would still reflect on other DDL/DML queries.

Answer (score 0):

DBF is the underlying operating system file in which the data gets stored. The SYSTEM.DBF contains the metadata that Oracle will use to manage the data (ie know what the users, tables, columns are).

If that's corrupted, you'll need to revert to some form of backup (eg an earlier snapshot of the appliance). You can probably find the system.dbf in linux (`locate system.dbf` would do) but there's not going to be anything you can do to fix it manually.

Answer (score 0):

+/DATA means that you are usinng ASM which is Oracles volume manager. I don't think that you can find the file easily with linux os commands.

A corruption in system.dbf is not good and you need a backup restore if you have one. I see that you are running Virtualbox so if you have a snapshot of the image, you can restore to that one.

If no backup and no image snapshot, then I'm afraid you need to install the virtualbox image again and redo you work.